# Aligning customized css button on responsive page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here I have created one page. Trying to learn responsive page design too.

[EXAMPLE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/karimkhan/9ScMs/2/)

Above second table, there is one line 'Twitter timline'.

In the same line above the 2nd table I have created button export to csv. **How can I align it to left?**

How can I place small rounded button there?

HTML

```
<h3> Twitter time line </h3>
<table class="table table-condensed">
  <thead>
    <tr class="active">
      <td class="active">Results</td>
      <td class="success">Date</td>
      <td class="warning">Time</td>
      <td class="danger">Twitter user</td>
      <td class="info">Reach</td>
      <td class="active">Contant</td>
      <td class="active">Tweet</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="active">
      <td class="active">1</td>
      <td class="success">john</td>
      <td class="warning">carry</td>
      <td class="danger">..dfd.</td>
      <td class="info">.dfd..</td>
      <td class="active">.fdfd..</td>
      <td class="success">...dfd</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="row demo-row">
<div class="col-xs-6">
     <h3> Twitter time line </h3>

</div>
<div class="col-xs-3"> <a href="#fakelink" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary">Export </a>

</div>
```

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/7L9Mr/7/)

[read more about bootstrap grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)

Comment: Can you please tell me what is your logic here? you changed `col`, I dont know about it

Comment: can you please tell me logic behind col and row here?

Comment: i've used bootstrap long back at the time of bootstrap2. not much familiar with bootstrap3. the `.row` class will take up the full available width. it's be considered to have a 12 columns of equal width. so inside it, if you specify another `div` with class `col-xs-6` it's take half of the space available for the row. `col-xs-3` will take next 25% and you can see the remaining 25% empty..

Comment: @cyclic find more  info here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/ read about grid system

Comment: @cyclic i solved the problem first, can you please explain why you accepted the other answer?

Comment: @cyclic where do you want those export to csv buttons to be?

Comment: In same line as "twitter timeline", but floated on right

Comment: @cyclic http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/7L9Mr/10/
it's the default rendering of `h1.. h6` elements taking place.. i've overridden it using `h3{margin-top:0px !important}`

Answer (score 0):

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/erenyener/7L9Mr/9/)

```
<div class="row buttonWithText">
    <h3> Twitter time line </h3>
    <div class="col-xs-3 export">
         <a href="#fakelink" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary">Export </a>
    </div>
</div>


body > div.row.buttonWithText
{
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

div.col-xs-3.export
{
      vertical-align:middle; 
}

h3{
    float:left;
    margin:0px;
    display:table-cell;  
    line-height:45px;
    }
```